# How to pass arguments to a function to connect to database

Tags: sql, r, sqlite, function

I would like to create a function to connect to a SQLite database by passing it two parameters: database name and table.

I tried this:

```
sqLiteConnect <- function(database, table) {
  con <- dbConnect("SQLite", dbname = database)
  query <- dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM  ", table)
  fetch(query, n = -1)
  }
```

But I pass `result <- sqLiteConnect(primary_database, "table_name")` I get `Error in sqliteExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : RS-DBI driver: (error in statement: near "  ": syntax error)`

If I change my function to

```
sqLiteConnect <- function(database, table) {
  con <- dbConnect("SQLite", dbname = database)
  query <- dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM  ", table, "")
  fetch(query, n = -1)
  }
```

I get `Error in sqliteExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : unused argument ("")`

I guess the problem is in concatenating a variable to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dbSendQuery requires the SQL statement as a single character string (it does not take the table as an argument), so you would need to create it using either paste() or sprintf(), for example:

```
sqLiteConnect <- function(database, table) {
 con <- dbConnect("SQLite", dbname = database)
 query <- dbSendQuery(con, paste("SELECT * FROM ", table, ";", sep="")) 
 fetch(query, n = -1)
 }
```

Comment: I tried your function and R gives a `Warning messages:
1: RS-DBI driver warning: (closing pending result sets before closing this connection)`. But if I try to add `close(con)` to the function I get `Error in UseMethod("close") : 
  no applicable method for 'close' applied to an object of class "c('SQLiteConnection', 'DBIConnection', 'SQLiteObject', 'DBIObject', 'dbObjectId')"
In addition: Warning message:
RS-DBI driver warning: (closing pending result sets before closing this connection)`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I am guessing you are using the package RMySQL. If so the correct function to use to close the connection is dbDisconnect(con) -- see the reference guide for that package, page 3.